# Set CSS for GoogleMaps within Bootstrap row

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following document structure, but the GoogleMap doesn't show up. It works, when I do not put it into the `row` `col` structure for using the grid system of bootstrap. How do I need to describe my classes within the CSS, so it is still being recognized? I guess the `GISContainer`does not have the correct sizing anymore, since it is within the col class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="GISContainer" id="GISContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="GISMap" v-el:map></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.PageWrapper {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.row, .col {
  height: 100%;
}

.GISContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.GISMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

**JS**

```
function initGISMap(selector) {
    map = new google.maps.Map(selector, {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9, 151.2),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    searchMarker = createMarker();
}
```

**VUE**

```
var Vue = require('vue');
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);

window.app = new Vue({
   el: '#GISContainer',
   data: {
      defaultMapLocation: 'Street'
   },
   methods: {
      init: function() {
         initGISMap(this.$els.map);
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put `.GISMap` into containers (`row`,`col`) that are not 100% height, therefore you need to do this..

```
.row, .col-md-6 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

or use a specific height for the `.GISMap`, eg:

```
.GISMap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work with the `.row, .col {
  height: 100%;
}` approach

Comment: I want to avoid to use a specific height, as the map should always be 100% in height of the screen.

Comment: It would be `.col-md-6`, not just `.col`

Comment: but this would mean I need to style this for every type of col type and cannot do it on a general level?

Comment: Sure you can just give it a new class like `map-container` : http://www.bootply.com/j9iHPVXQbc

Answer (score 0):

For google maps if you want use height 100%  you have to set all parent containers to a 100%

then also

```
.row and .col 
 {
    height 100%;
 }
```